# Web Parameter Tampering in Angular and Springboot

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-boot

I have a Web Application with Angular as front end and Spring Boot webservices as the backend. i am able to perform "Web Parameter Tampering" attack on one of my post call which inserts data in to my database. Has anyone solved this before ?

Appreciate your help.

Angular :

```
$scope.submitRequest = function() {
                ar.createRequest.save({
                   orderNum : orderNum
                   ...
                }, function() {

                }, function (httpResponse){

                });
            };
```

SpringBoot :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/...", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @CrossOrigin
    public ResponseEntity<?> createRequest(@RequestBody OrderDTO orderdto){

     RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
     .......
     .....   
  return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Comment: could you please post some code samples?

Comment: i am using angular resource to talk to spring boot webservices.

Comment: added sample code snippets